# Why is angular translate async in version +2

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I am using angular translate version 1.x for quite a while.
The use of the $translate service is really easy.

In a controller, you can simply write:

```
$scope.whatever = $translate('WHATEVER');
```

But in angular translate 2.x that has changed.
Now the service works async.
The simple and fast to write above statement has now become:

```
$translate('WHATEVER').then(function (whatever) {
    $scope.whatever= whatever;
});
```

This makes things more complicated.
I don't really understand the need for this.
In most scenario's (?) the translation files will be downloaded once and then getting a translation value should be really fast. Why the need of handling this async?

Can anyone explain why this change was made?

Thanks

Comment: I found that you can use $translate.instant('TRANSLATION_ID'); to achieve the "synchronous" behavior. So that helps. Remains the question why one would want to use the asynchronous version.

Comment: Probably to support asynchronous loading of translation resources/files from server.

Answer (score 0):

You should think the way around: 
Who guarantees you, that all language files are loaded in time or at all. And as you're in a browser environment, everything retrieved from somewhere is asynchronous in terms of network speed etc. 
So in case one "loading" process hangs, the whole application will be unusable because it is waiting for a correct reply/answer. So, if you do it synchronous, you'll have to wait until everything is loaded - just think of big images or translation files in our case here and maybe these are even unneeded translation files, because you're just using some languages out of the language stack as your personal preference.

Async loading speeds up the whole process of rendering the DOM and giving your "application" already a final state that you can work with, no matter, how many promises haven't been resolved yet. 
This is one of the "big" natures of the Web Applications and yes, might cause headaches sometimes. Sometimes you'll ask yourself "why not wait this 500ms until everything is there?", but it could be the case, that one of the webservers is down or just overloaded and then you'll have to wait and wait and wait as a user. Do you always want this?